# PHP форматирование в VScode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Использую в VScode для форматирования кода **intelephense**.
Имеется код вида:

```
<div <?php if($variable) { echo 'data="1"'; } ?> ></div>
```

При форматировании, intelephense переносит скобки конструкции `if-else` на новые строки.

```
<div <?php if ($variable) {
                echo 'data="1"';
            } ?>></div>
```

Какую настройку задать, чтобы intelephense не переносил фигурные скобки на новые строки?